# Timeout when passing variables with the url and fopen() in php

Tags: php, get, fopen

I have done quite a bit of searching and cannot quite find my answer. My problem is that I am trying to call a link with GET variables attached to it and it just hangs and hangs until connection times out. When I just literally call the link in a web browser it works fine no problem.

Here is the fopen() php code example:

```
<?php
$url = "https://www.mysite.com/folder/second_folder/file.php?varA=val1&varB=val2&varC=val3&varD=val4&varE=val5";
$ch = fopen($url, 'r');

if(!$ch){
    echo "could not open!!! $url";
} else {
    echo "Success! ($url)";
}
?>
```

I can call file.php without the GET variables just fine. Returns with no error.

**NOTE**: I will say that file.php with one of the var's that get passed, does some functions and then does a header Location rewrite. I do not think it is even getting to this point when it does a connect timeout though because when I had problems, I put in a "check point" prior to the header Location point which should email me, and it does not email me.

*Again*, if I run the URL in a web browser it works just fine.

So what is going on if anyone can help me? I just need to run the URL as if PHP is clicking on the links. I have used fopen before but for some reason it does not work now. Also cURL did not work on this.

Comment: thats not a file on your own site is it?

Comment: it is a file on my site... the reason I call it with the full link is because when I did it locally, it said it wasn't even a recognized directory or file, neither of which are true. I checked and double checked

Comment: there should be no reason to parse a file on your own site via the web server.

Comment: not to be too argumentative, but it can be helpful in some cases and I do have my own reasons, primarily to keep from reduplicating code on another file, and also to keep from messing with the production 'file.php'.

Comment: @Dagon is there a different way you prefer to pass info to a file on your site that is as simple as the GET method across an URL? I realize you have far more experience than I do, and maybe than I ever will. I am just trying to work with a situation that was handed to me and that I am working with until we eventually rewrite the structure and system.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing '' to " " in this case.

My working code is

`<?php $handle = fopen("c:\\folder\\resource.txt", "r"); ?>`

Comment: What if you changed it from r+

Comment: It's not really a writeable file nor should it be able to be called. I did try for kicks, but no go, immediate shut down because of the request type (including the writeable portion)

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to be using

```
$ch = file_get_contents($url);
```

Edit: cURL option

```
// open
$ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $page_data = curl_exec($ch);
    $page_info = curl_getinfo($ch); 


// close
curl_close ($ch);
```

Comment: tried file_get_contents($url); and still the same issue: hangs and hangs.

Comment: @jcsbrotha what happens when you go to the url in your web browser, and are you at the same URL you entered when the process finishes?

Comment: when i go to the URL in my web browser, it does its thing, then it does a header Location redirect. The problem is that it never even gets to that point of the script on that page when calling from fopen, file_get_contents() etc